# How can we create an object with same name as its class?

Tags: java, javac

How can we use same name for class and object , without any issues from the compiler ?

```
class A{
    public static void main (){
        A A = new A ();
    }
}
```

Or

```
class A{
    public static void main(){
        String String="java";
        System.out.println(String);
    }
}
```

How does the java compiler handle this?

Comment: The most simple answer is: Because nothing says that it should give an issue. But of course, that doesn't make it a good idea ;-)

Comment: Why should I? It works....

Comment: Sir Florian please take a look at the question again..!

Comment: If you enter this exact code, the compiler will NOT give an issue. It works. Trust me.

Comment: Or rather than trusting Florian, try it and see it for yourself.

Comment: I already tried this.....that is what i m asking...how?  It doesn't show any ambiguity while calling a function that has been defind static....????

Comment: That's because `A.someStaticMethod()` means exactly the same, no matter if `A` is a class name or a variable name. So there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @Jesper It isn't actually. It's because the declaration of a variable named `A` shadows the declaration of the class `A` in an outer scope.

Comment: @EJP What I meant with "exactly the same" is that the effect is the same - the static method is called, no matter if it is qualified with the class name `A` or the variable name `A`.

Answer (score 3):

**In Java it is absolutely correct to specify the name of the class and the name of the variable to be exactly the same.** The compiler understands the syntax so it knows what part of the program represents the identifier and what part represents the class name.

**But you should never do it as it will become a readability nightmare.** Absolutely misleading and violating Java Naming Conventions.

Comment: It is purely a matter of scoping. Not syntax.

Comment: @EJP I'm interested... what do you mean by "scoping"?